# Netlify deployment of Jekyll fails on using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jekyll, netlify

I am using docker-compose to build my Jekyll project:

```
version: "3"
services:
  site:
    command: jekyll serve
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/srv/jekyll
      - $PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 35729:35729
      - 3000:3000
      -   80:4000
```

The folder structure looks like

```
[projectname]/
├── mysite/
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── Gemfile
│   ├── vendor
│   └── [...]
├── docker-compose.yml
└── vendor
```

I am now trying to deploy to Netlify, but the folder structure seems to bring issues, as it's all under mysite and not in the folder above. However, through using docker-compose, I don't know how to change that. The error I am getting when deploying on Netlify is here:

```
11:08:51 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:08:52 AM: Starting build script
11:08:52 AM: Installing dependencies
11:08:54 AM: Downloading and installing node v8.12.0...
11:08:54 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
11:08:54 AM: 
#
11:08:54 AM:                                              1.9%
11:08:54 AM: 
#########################
11:08:54 AM:                           35.1%
11:08:54 AM: 
######################################
11:08:54 AM: ################                    76.1%
11:08:54 AM: 
##################################################
11:08:54 AM: ###################### 100.0%
11:08:54 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
11:08:54 AM: Checksums matched!
11:08:56 AM: Now using node v8.12.0 (npm v6.4.1)
11:08:56 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
11:08:57 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
11:08:57 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
11:08:57 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
11:08:57 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
11:08:57 AM: unset GOOS;
11:08:57 AM: unset GOARCH;
11:08:57 AM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.10.linux.amd64';
11:08:57 AM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.10.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
11:08:57 AM: go version >&2;
11:08:57 AM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.10.linux.amd64.env';
11:08:57 AM: go version go1.10 linux/amd64
11:08:57 AM: Installing missing commands
11:08:57 AM: Verify run directory
11:08:57 AM: Executing user command: jekyll build
11:08:57 AM: /usr/local/bin/build: line 32: jekyll: command not found
11:08:57 AM: Caching artifacts
11:08:58 AM: Started saving pip cache
11:08:58 AM: Finished saving pip cache
11:08:58 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Started saving go dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
11:08:58 AM: Cached node version v8.12.0
11:08:58 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
11:08:58 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:08:58 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
11:08:58 AM: Finished processing build request in 7.670431208s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netlify allows a `base` directory location for a project to be set using the `netlify.toml`

`netlify.toml` (needs to be in the root of the repository)

```
[build]
  # Directory to change to before starting a build. 
  # This is where we will look for package.json/.nvmrc/etc.
  base = "project/"
  # Directory (relative to root of your repo) that contains the deploy-ready 
  # HTML files and assets generated by the build.
  publish = "project/build-output/"
```

Read about other options [in the docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/)

Another option is to move your `mysite` folder to it's own repository, since Netlify does not need the docker configuration to setup the environment to run `jekyll` because it supports it by default.